# Curious behavior of the Dim instruction in Microsoft Visual Basic

Tags: vba

I am using VBA 7.1.1092 and I have the very strange (but I am probably missing something obvious) behavior. This is the code:

```
Function test(s As String) As String
    test = s
End Function
Function test2(p As String) As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim t As String
    s = p
    test2 = test(s)
End Function
Function test1(p As String) As String
    Dim s, t As String
    s = p
    test1 = test(s)
End Function
```

Function test2 does compile while the compilation of test1 fails on the instruction

```
test1=test(s)
```

with the error on s being "ByRef incompatible". I thought that the declarations in test1 and test2 were identical. So, what am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Dim s, t As String` declares `t` as string but `s` as variant. It wouldn't normally matter very much, but you need `Dim s as string, t As String` when passing arguments to functions.

Comment: Or you could write `test((s))` but change the dim statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA

```
Dim s, t As String
```

equivalent to:

```
Dim s as variant
Dim t as String
```

As type of `s` is omitted so by default it will be `variant`.

you will have to declare like this:

```
Dim s As String
Dim t As String
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer but that seems incoherent when reading microsoft VBA manual [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement) There I read the following thing: `Dim a, b, c As Single, x, y As Double, i As Integer
' a, b, and c are all Single; x and y are both Double`

Comment: Not sure, why it is mentioned like that. You may refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement

Comment: That's not VBA. Is it visual basic .net.

Comment: Yes thank you very much I missed the difference between VBA and Visual Basic .net My mistake. Thanks again to both of you.

Comment: James, could you accept the answer please if it has helped?